# R CMD BATCH Issue: Unexpected Input Error

Tags: r

I am trying to run an R script using the following,

```
c:\Progra~1\R\R-2.13.1\bin\R CMD BATCH "test.R"
```

The file test.R contains

```
print ("Hello World")
```

However, I keep getting the following error. The above example is kept simple with just 1 line to make debugging easier.

```
R version 2.13.1 (2011-07-08)
Copyright (C) 2011 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
ISBN 3-900051-07-0
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> pError: unexpected input in "print ("Hello World")
"
Execution halted
```

It works if I add a ; sign after print ("Hello World"), but if there are other lines in test.R those lines never get executed.

Could you please advise.

Comment: My guess is that your editor is putting an odd character at the end of that line.

Comment: Hi Joshua, that seems to be perhaps the case. I was using Textpad to edit test.R. Once I created the file in Unix and copied over to Windows, it worked without any error. Thanks !

Comment: @xbsd Can you please add this as an answer to your question? In that way it can get marked as answered and perhaps be helpful to other people searching for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Textpad to edit test.R. But for some reason it introduced some non-printable characters I suppose.

Once I created test.R in Unix and copied over to Windows, it worked without any error.